# Bash grep regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have the following string that gets pulled from my file
`__version__ = '10.11.12'`

The version can also be in the format of `0.1.2` or even `100.20.30`

I have the following bash command, but my current issue is I only grab one value in each number
`MODULE_VERSION=$(cat <%= project %>/__init__.py | grep -o '[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]')`

I would like to modify the grep regular expression to grab all the numerical values of the version.

Comment: You are using a BSD grep, right? Install the GNU version, it extracts all occurrences.  BTW, you need `grep -o '[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*'` to extract `10.11.12`.

Comment: `MODULE_VERSION=$(cat <%= project %>/__init__.py | grep -o '[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+')` try this.. `+` checks for 1 or more numbers, `*` checks for 0 or more numbers. Use whichever suits your need.

Comment: Do you really have a directory named `<%= project %>`? That needs to be quoted.

Comment: it is using gulp.js. it is a python generator that allows users to name the project whatever they want and will always pull that project name. So no I do not really have a directory called <%= project %>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You current regex '[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]' is going to have false positives and false negatives. The '.' character is reserved to mean any character, so you have to escape it using a backslash to have it match only the character '.' In addition '[0-9]' will only match one occurrence of a digit. Your regular expression will match any 5 characters that have a digit at positions 1, 3, and 5.

**Example of false positive:**

1a2b3

**Example of false negative:**

100.20.30

With grep you can count occurrences of a character. See the grep man page for more information. If you are trying to match the examples you gave (XX.XX.XX | X.X.X | XXX.XX.XX) The following regular expression would match all instances and only instances following that pattern. The downside is that it is very long (there might be a better way to write this please edit if you know one).

```
grep -o -E '([0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2})|([0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])|([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2})'
```

If you are less worried about false positives you can simplify this to:

```
grep -E -o '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}'
```

This will match some instances you have not specified.

**Examples of false positives**

 1.12.12

 123.1.1

 12.1.12

 the list goes on...

As has been said in the comments gnu grep will match all occurrences. (I have tested these regular expressions with GNU grep 2.20)

Comment: Thank you. While this is the response that I was looking for I decided to go with a different approach.

The command that wound up working for me was simply
`MODULE_VERSION=$(python -c "import <%= project %>s; print(<%= project %>.__version__)")

Comment: That seems like a much safe approach than using regular expressions to detect version number. Glad you found a solution